# Invalid Bundle error when trying to upload new version to itunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode8

I am trying to upload a version to TestFlight. A few days ago, uploading to TestFlight worked perfectly. Today i receive the following error:

```
Invalid Bundle - A nested bundle contains simulator platform listed in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Info.plist key.
```

I searched for CFBundleSupportedPlatforms in all info plists and could not find anything. I even made sure this key does not appear in any file on my Mac. Is it an issue on my side or in Apple's side?

Comment: are you using Google map sdk???

Comment: Same issue. Yes i'm using Google map sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Check all **plist** file in your app(even framework file)in that plist you will have **CFBundleSupportedPlatforms** key, for this key only one value should be there that is "**iPhoneOS**" rather than this if you have any keys delete those then issue will be solved.

Comment: My project's All plist file contains only one value "iPhoneOS" for CFBundleSupportedPlatforms. But still getting same error. Is there an any other solution?